# Django Rest Swagger Not showing up all the APIs

Tags: django, openapi

I am working with Django Rest swagger. But it's not showing up all the APIs.

The url paths for /tickets are missing:

[image]

Even path to /dj-rest-auth/user/ is missing as well:

[image]

**Backend/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='API')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #path('api/v1/', include(api_urlpatterns)),
    #path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('api/', include('ticket.urls')),
    path('swagger/', schema_view)
]
```

**Tickets/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from ticket import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('tickets/', views.ticket_list),
    path('tickets/<int:pk>/', views.ticket_detail),

]
```

My directory structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your views that are not appearing?

Comment: Please try my answer, by the way, do you know how to export these API and import them to `Postman`?

Comment: @Queen you mean python3 manage.py generateschema --file openapi-schema.yml , something like this??

Comment: @senarijit1618 Yes

Comment: @senarijit1618 For more details, you can see this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71260487/how-to-import-swagger-format-openapi-to-postman-from-django-rest-swagger-withou

Comment: @senarijit1618 Hi, do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {    
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    .......
    .......
}
```

Comment: Yeps. Settings.py have the same permission classes as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going in settings.py file and set DEBUG=True.